# Uploading large files on Heroku with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm about to embark on a hobby project where I'll upload lots of files to S3.  Some of the files will be large 50-100MB.  I would like to use Heroku but can fallback on EC2 instead if needed.

Will Heroku + Carrierwave + S3 work for this?  Or are there limitations to file uploads?  If so what's a good alternative?

Also curious if there are any cool uploading libraries like uploadify but w/o the flash.

Thanks!

Comment: I have used Carrierwave uploading to Rackspace Cloud Files testing my app on Heroku and it works fine. However, these are only files less than 10MB.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recommend taking advantage of S3's direct-upload feature. This will allow your users to upload straight to your S3 account (in a secure fashion), bypassing the upload to Heroku at all. This keeps your Dynos free to handle normal requests and avoids the high file-upload processing CPU costs as well as memory limit problems.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

This gem appears to just what you're looking for: https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct

Comment: Bingo - just what I was looking for.  I wanted to do direct upload to S3 - yet have the ORM features of Carrierwave.  Thanks Corey!