# ROLLBACK when I upload file more 100M to S3 via server EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I can upload video less than 100M via EC2 to S3. But when I try to upload file more then 100M I have this problem:

The tail of production.rb:

```
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4] Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/RackMultipart20180220-14826-1x1yb8.mp4'
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4] [paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/RackMultipart20180220-14826-1x1yb8.mp4 to /tmp/b93945416b51d7b7076bcf9f697819dd20180220-14826-5mkak1.mp4
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4] [paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/b93945416b51d7b7076bcf9f697819dd20180220-14826-5mkak1.mp4 to /tmp/1c3b7d3617b75c8c2177c1dfde03e9ce20180220-14826-kklptr.mp4
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4] Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/1c3b7d3617b75c8c2177c1dfde03e9ce20180220-14826-kklptr.mp4'
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4]    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4] [paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/b93945416b51d7b7076bcf9f697819dd20180220-14826-5mkak1.mp4 to /tmp/1c3b7d3617b75c8c2177c1dfde03e9ce20180220-14826-bw0wgm.mp4
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4] Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/1c3b7d3617b75c8c2177c1dfde03e9ce20180220-14826-bw0wgm.mp4'
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4]    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
[dbe91a4c-0c42-48c2-8165-ae9f71cc39c4]   Rendering videos/new.slim within layouts/application
```

And in file `/tmp/`

```
total 809304
drwxrwxrwt  8 root   root        4096 Feb 20 13:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root   root        4096 Feb 13 14:54 ../
-rw-------  4 ubuntu ubuntu 133547466 Feb 20 13:09 1c3b7d3617b75c8c2177c1dfde03e9ce20180220-14826-bw0wgm.mp4
-rw-------  4 ubuntu ubuntu 133547466 Feb 20 13:09 1c3b7d3617b75c8c2177c1dfde03e9ce20180220-14826-kklptr.mp4
-rw-------  4 ubuntu ubuntu 133547466 Feb 20 13:09 b93945416b51d7b7076bcf9f697819dd20180220-14826-5mkak1.mp4
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root        4096 Feb 13 14:54 .font-unix/
-rwx------  1 ubuntu ubuntu        93 Feb 20 12:04 git-ssh-where-film-production-dunice.sh*
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root        4096 Feb 13 14:54 .ICE-unix/
-rw-------  1 ubuntu ubuntu 279808355 Feb 20 12:50 puma20180220-11196-cyloww
-rw-------  1 ubuntu ubuntu  14679270 Feb 20 12:50 RackMultipart20180220-11196-1t5jbyk.mp4
-rw-------  4 ubuntu ubuntu 133547466 Feb 20 13:09 RackMultipart20180220-14826-1x1yb8.mp4
drwx------  3 root   root        4096 Feb 14 06:41 systemd-private-8b23ec1f7e8644498bf0091b6fd675d2-systemd-timesyncd.service-xl7iRW/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root        4096 Feb 13 14:54 .Test-unix/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root        4096 Feb 13 14:54 .X11-unix/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root        4096 Feb 13 14:54 .XIM-unix/
```

I upload files via Paperclip. Locally it works without problem.

This command 
`file -b --mime '/tmp/1c3b7d3617b75c8c2177c1dfde03e9ce20180221-12338-1xbpmbo.mp4'`

return this:

```
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check storage space or free RAM?

```
df -h --total or free -m
```

also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749553/what-is-the-best-approach-to-handle-large-file-uploads-in-a-rails-app)

Comment: total : 990  used : 519  free : 268  shared : 36  buff/cache : 203  available : 278

Answer (score 0):

Another place is to check your server's nginx configuration.

Look for `client_max_body_size` in `nginx.conf`

Disclaimer: This is part of your server's configuration and not a part of your Rails application.

Comment: client_max_body_size 2000M;