# How to upload large video files on a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, video-upload

I have a Rails application set up on which users can upload video files. Some of these video files are about 20GB.

My configurations are as follows:
Ruby 2.2.6
Rails 4.2.0
Storage: Amazon S3
Database: MongoDB

I need to know what steps do I need to ensure a smooth and successful upload of these files?

Or if it is not feasible, then why? or alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: I would try either Rails ActiveStorage or CarrierWave. Get a simple upload to work and once you do, update your question with your new code if you're still having issues.

Comment: There are some good tips in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749553/what-is-the-best-approach-to-handle-large-file-uploads-in-a-rails-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best approach to handle large file uploads in a rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749553/what-is-the-best-approach-to-handle-large-file-uploads-in-a-rails-app)